# Use NULL as a valid value in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with one parameter, `@ID`, which is an integer that might be zero.  When it is zero, I want to use it as if it is null.  So here is how I have written my query:

```
If @ID = 0
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID IS NULL
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID;
```

This is quite inelegant.  Surely there is a way to write the `WHERE` clause in such a way that makes duplicating the `SELECT` statement unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase this more simply using:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE COALESCE(ID, 0) = @id;
```

Next, you probably do not want to do this. It will prevent SQL Server from using an index. Similarly, `OR` is likely to prevent optimization as well.

Probably your best bet is your current code, or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IS NULL AND @id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = @ID;   -- not sure if `@id <> 0` is needed here
```

With this or your approach, you probably need `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to ensure that an index is always used.

Comment: In light of your comments, I've decided to stick with my inelegant but simple code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine them using AND/OR logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (@Id != 0 AND ID = @ID)
OR (@Id = 0 AND ID IS NULL);
```